# how to navigate to actaul navigation url?

Tags: asp.net, radgrid

in my code when i set

```
   link.NavigateUrl = Common.grdTextCell(gridDataItem["URL"].Text);
```

For the hyperlink in the rad grid.

when i click it it redirect to the application domainName+url rathere than only URL.

How to deattach the Domain and redirect it to the actual navigation url.

```
http://SomeDomainName/Controls/www.yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure `gridDataItem["URL"]` starts with `http://` (or `https://` depending)

If the URL to navigate to does not start with a protocol (I.e. `http://` or `https://`) the browser will assume the link is part of the current domain.

I would have something like the following...

```
string url = gridDataItem["URL"].Text;
if(!url.StartsWith("http://"))
   url = "http://" + url;
link.NavigateUrl = Common.grdTextCell(url);
```

You obviously need to modify the above should you need to use `https://` instead.

Comment: if it start with that wount it redirect like the flawed URL?

Comment: @Novice, if the URL in the hyperlink does not start with a protocol (I.e. `http://` or `https://`), the browser will assume that the link is on the same domain

Comment: thanks the above comment is of great use, i could not predict it, this is the case, thanks a lot..

Comment: @Novice, you're welcome... please remember to mark as accepted should it be exactly what you're after